# Remove a navbar in WebView for Android App

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I use a webView for one part of my android application. But in the `HTML` Code of the page, i want remove a navbar from the website. I've try this but that's not work :

**Exemple** :
In google.com website, i want remove the button "random search" in my WebView.

```
 WebViewClient WebClient = new WebViewClient(){
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                            view.loadUrl(url);
                            return true;
                        }
                    };


                    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview52);
                    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
                    myWebView.setWebViewClient(WebClient);
                    myWebView.loadUrl("https://mywebsite.com/xxx");
                    myWebView.loadUrl
                            ("javascript:(function() { " +
                                    "document.getElementsByClassName('navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                                    "document.getElementById('navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top').style.display='none';");
```

The HTML Code i want remove from the webpage :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    (...)
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `(function() {` from your javascript function and getElementById is unnecessary:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top')[0].style.display='none'");
```

Consider using [evaluateJavascript](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) instead of `loadUrl("javascript:...` (API 19+)